# How to drag and drop table columns in react js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-table, drag-and-drop

I trying to make table columns change order by drag and drop , i tried a lot of libraries and the best i could do is this :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './list_de_tournees.css'
const Table = ({ columns }) => {
  const [currentColumns, setCurrentColumns] = useState(columns);

  const handleDragStart = (e, columnIndex) => {
    e.dataTransfer.setData('columnIndex', columnIndex);
  };

  const handleDragOver = (e, columnIndex) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const dragIndex = e.dataTransfer.getData('columnIndex');
    if (dragIndex !== columnIndex) {
      const newColumns = [...currentColumns];
      const [draggedColumn] = newColumns.splice(dragIndex, 1);
      newColumns.splice(columnIndex, 0, draggedColumn);
      setCurrentColumns(newColumns);
    }
  };

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {currentColumns.map((column, index) => (
            <th
              key={column.id}
              draggable
              onDr
              onDragStart={(e) => handleDragStart(e, index)}
              onDragOver={(e) => handleDragOver(e, index)}
            >
              {column.Header}
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          {currentColumns.map((column, index) => (
            <td key={column.id}>
              {column.accessor === 'name' && 'alice'}
              {column.accessor === 'age' && '30'}
              {column.accessor === 'country' && 'USA'}
            </td>
          ))}
        </tr>
        <tr>
          {currentColumns.map((column, index) => (
            <td key={column.id}>
              {column.accessor === 'name' && 'Bob'}
              {column.accessor === 'age' && '25'}
              {column.accessor === 'country' && 'Canada'}
            </td>
          ))}
        </tr>
        <tr>
          {currentColumns.map((column, index) => (
            <td key={column.id}>
              {column.accessor === 'name' && 'Charlie'}
              {column.accessor === 'age' && '35'}
              {column.accessor === 'country' && 'UK'}
            </td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

const columns = [
  {
    Header: 'Name',
    accessor: 'name',
    id: '1',
  },
  {
    Header: 'Age',
    accessor: 'age',
    id: '2',
  },
  {
    Header: 'Country',
    accessor: 'country',
    id: '3',
  },
];

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table columns={columns} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

but I want it the table to be a static html table and draggable at the same time , i tried this :

```
  <td draggable onDragStart={(e) => handleDragStart(e, 0)} onDragOver={(e) => handleDragOver(e, 0)}>Alice</td>
    <td draggable onDragStart={(e) => handleDragStart(e, 1)} onDragOver={(e) => handleDragOver(e, 1)}>30</td>
    <td draggable onDragStart={(e) => handleDragStart(e, 2)} onDragOver={(e) => handleDragOver(e, 2)}>USA</td>
```

but it didn't work , I couldn't drag it .
I tried this in simple project of html,css and vanilla js and it work perfectly here [example](https://jsbin.com/sazeral/edit?html,output)

Comment: Did you check out the [react-table-hoc-draggable-columns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table-hoc-draggable-columns) package? Also, 
take a look at this beautiful example someone created: [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-goodall-f8swq)

Comment: @DineshMsd the problem react-table-hoc-draggable-columns only work with react table , what I want is to be abel to make an html table draggable like i did with vanilla js  , I'm trying to apply it in react .

Comment: Why don't you use Tools like chatGPT or BardAI to convert your VanillaJS code to ReactJS code? I tried with your simple code written in vanilla js and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

To implement column dragging and reordering in a React table, you can follow these steps:

First, make sure each table cell has the `draggable` attribute and the `onDragStart` and `onDragOver` events to initiate and control the drag process.

```
<td
  draggable
  onDragStart={(e) => handleDragStart(e, 0)}
  onDragOver={(e) => handleDragOver(e, 0)}
>
  Alice
</td>
<td
  draggable
  onDragStart={(e) => handleDragStart(e, 1)}
  onDragOver={(e) => handleDragOver(e, 1)}
>
  30
</td>
<td
  draggable
  onDragStart={(e) => handleDragStart(e, 2)}
  onDragOver={(e) => handleDragOver(e, 2)}
>
  USA
</td>
```

Next, ensure you have the `handleDragStart` and `handleDragOver` functions defined correctly in your component to handle the drag and reorder process. You can use React state to keep track of column positions.

Here's an example of how you could implement these functions:

```
const handleDragStart = (e, columnIndex) => {
  e.dataTransfer.setData('columnIndex', columnIndex);
};

const handleDragOver = (e, columnIndex) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const dragIndex = e.dataTransfer.getData('columnIndex');

  // Implement column reordering logic here
};
```

In the `handleDragOver` function, you should perform the logic to reorder the columns based on `dragIndex` and `columnIndex`. You can update React state with the new column positions so that the table will render correctly with the new order.

Your complete component code might look something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Table = ({ columns }) => {
  const [currentColumns, setCurrentColumns] = useState(columns);

  const handleDragStart = (e, columnIndex) => {
    e.dataTransfer.setData('columnIndex', columnIndex);
  };

  const handleDragOver = (e, columnIndex) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const dragIndex = e.dataTransfer.getData('columnIndex');
    if (dragIndex !== columnIndex) {
      const newColumns = [...currentColumns];
      const [draggedColumn] = newColumns.splice(dragIndex, 1);
      newColumns.splice(columnIndex, 0, draggedColumn);
      setCurrentColumns(newColumns);
    }
  };

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {currentColumns.map((column, index) => (
            <th
              key={column.id}
              draggable
              onDragStart={(e) => handleDragStart(e, index)}
              onDragOver={(e) => handleDragOver(e, index)}
            >
              {column.Header}
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      {/* Rest of the table */}
    </table>
  );
};

// Rest of your code
```

With this implementation, you should be able to drag and reorder the columns in your React application. Make sure to handle column positions in your state properly and render the table accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some little corrections on @nimeom answer. For properly working you have to add **allowDrop** callback and modify th properties like this:

```
<th
draggable
onDragStart={(e) => handleDragStart(e, index)}
onDragOver={allowDrop}
onDrop={(e) => handleDragOver(e, index)
>
```

This is all the joined code using React Functional Components:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Table = () => {

    const columns = [
        {
            Header: 'Name',
            accessor: 'name',
            id: '1',
        },
        {
            Header: 'Age',
            accessor: 'age',
            id: '2',
        },
        {
            Header: 'Country',
            accessor: 'country',
            id: '3',
        },
    ];


    const [currentColumns, setCurrentColumns] = useState(columns);

    const handleDragStart = (e, columnIndex) => {
        e.dataTransfer.setData('columnIndex', columnIndex);
        console.log("columnIndex:");
        console.log(columnIndex);
    };

    const allowDrop= (e, columnIndex) =>  {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    const handleDragOver = (e, columnIndex) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("columnIndex:");
        console.log(columnIndex);
        const dragIndex = e.dataTransfer.getData('columnIndex');
        console.log("dragIndex:");
        console.log(dragIndex);
        if (dragIndex !== columnIndex) {
            const newColumns = [...currentColumns];
            const [draggedColumn] = newColumns.splice(dragIndex, 1);
            newColumns.splice(columnIndex, 0, draggedColumn);
            setCurrentColumns(newColumns);
        }
    };

    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    {currentColumns.map((column, index) => (
                        <th
                            key={column.id}
                            draggable
                            onDragStart={(e) => handleDragStart(e, index)}
                            onDragOver={allowDrop}
                            onDrop={(e) => handleDragOver(e, index)}
                        >
                            {column.Header}
                        </th>
                    ))}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            {/* Rest of the table */}
        </table>
    );
};
```